# Get matrix entries related to an image asset via specific field

Tags: entries, assets, matrix, entries-field

I have a Matrix field that has an Entries field. I want to get those entries, in the selected order, removing entries that don’t have an image asset assigned to the `pageImage` field.

**Attempt 1**
Gets correct entries but doesn’t maintain the selection order.

```twig
block.entries.relatedTo('and', {
  targetElement: craft.assets.kind('image'),
  field: 'pageImage'
})
```

**Attempt 2**
Same result as above. Correct entries but wrong order.

```twig
craft.entries.relatedTo('and', {
  sourceElement: block
}, {
  targetElement: craft.assets.kind('image'),
  field: 'pageImage'
})
```

Setting the `field` value in the first statement results in an empty result set.

**Attempt 3**
Seems to work but generates extra queries.

```twig
{% set ids = block.entries.ids() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.id(ids).fixedOrder(ids).relatedTo({
  targetElement: craft.assets.kind('image'),
  field: 'pageImage'
}) %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you said that **Attempt 1** was giving you the correct entries, just in the wrong order, if you have two blocks, you will probably find that you’re getting all blocks’ related entries each time. Because when you set that `relatedTo` param on `block.entries`, you’re actually overriding the existing `relatedTo` param that the Entries field type set, which limits entries to just those that are related to the current block. So with a little more testing you’ll find that’s more than just an ordering problem.

**Attempt 2** is the right way to go - finding entries that are explicitly related to both the current block *and* some number of assets. If you want those entries to show up in the order they were related within the current block, you just need to set the `order` param. In this case you’ll want to set that to `sources1.sortOrder`, as `sources1` is the alias that the `craft_relations` will get when it’s joined into the query to aid in a `sourceElement` relation param for the first time.

```twig
craft.entries({
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { sourceElement: block },
        { targetElement: craft.assets.kind('image'), field: 'pageImage' }
    ],
    order: 'sources1.sortOrder'
})
```

One thing I would recommend is, if you are going to be running this same query on multiple Matrix blocks on the same page, you should define that `craft.assets` ElementCriteriaModel outside of the main for-loop. That will save Craft a DB query for each block.

```twig
{% set allImages = craft.assets.kind('image').limit(null) %}

{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries({
        relatedTo: [
            'and',
            { sourceElement: block },
            { targetElement: allImages, field: 'pageImage' }
        ],
        order: 'sources1.sortOrder'
    }) %}

    ...

{% endfor %}
```